# How should I display in a view all the ingredients in from a recipe when I am using many-to-many relationship in EF?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

So I want to display in a View all the Ingredients that a recipe has. I have created with EF a Ingredient table and a Recipe table. The relationship is many-to-many. I can't get how to show in one view the ingredients of a recipe.

I tried to modify the models so that I can show the ingredients, but I was able to see only one ingredient.

This is my Ingredient class:

```
namespace Licenta.Models
{
    public class Ingredient
    {
        [Key]
        public int IDIngredient { get; set; }
        public string Nume { get; set; }
        public int Kcal { get; set; }
        public int Pro { get; set; }
        public int Carbo { get; set; }
        public int Fat { get; set; }
        public IList<Recipe> Recipes { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is my Recipe class:

```
namespace Licenta.Models
{
    public class Recipe
    {
        [Key]
        public int IDRecipe { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Desc { get; set; }
        public string Steps { get; set; }
        public int Kcal { get; set; }
        public int Pro { get; set; }
        public int Carbo { get; set; }
        public int Fat { get; set; }
        public IList<Ingredient> Ingredients { get; set; }

    }
}
```

And this is my View:

```
@model Licenta.Models.Recipe

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}

<h2>Recipe Details</h2>

<div>
    <h4>Recipe</h4>
    <hr />
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>
            Name:
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Name)
        </dd>
        <dt>
            Calories:
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Kcal) calorii
        </dd>
        <dt>
            Proteins:
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Pro) grame
        </dd>
        <dt>
            Carbs:
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Carbo) grame
        </dd>
        <dt>
            Fat:
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Fat) grame
        </dd>
        <dt>
            Description:
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Desc)
        </dd>
        <dt>
            Steps:
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Steps)
        </dd>
        <dt>
            Ingredients:
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Ingredients)
        </dd>
    </dl>
</div>
```

The controller that I am using is this one:

```
namespace Licenta.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {

        private DataContext db = new DataContext();

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Recipes()
        {
            return View(db.Recipes.ToList());
        }

        public ActionResult Details(int? id)
        {
            if(id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Recipe recipe = db.Recipes.Find(id);

            if(recipe == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }

            return View(recipe);
        }

    }
}
```

I also saw that EF created a RecipesIngredients table in my database. How should I use that table to list the ingredients of my recipe?

Comment: if you set a breakpoint on `return View(recipe)`, is `recipe.Ingredients` null?

Comment: Apparently yes. Even though I created in my RecipesIngredients table a row which specifies that the recipe with the ID 1 should have the ingredient with the ID 1

Comment: what about if you change `db.Recipes.Find(id);` to `db.Recipes.Include(y => y.Ingredients).Single(x => x.Id == id)`

Comment: It gives me this error: "Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type".

Comment: please include `using System.Linq;` and `using System.Data.Entity;` at the top of your class

Comment: I added the includes and now when I run the code, in the View I see that the DisplayFor is showing 1. Is this the id of the ingredient? I changed db.Recipes.Find(id) to db.Recipes.Include(y => y.Ingredients).Single(x => x.IDRecipe == id);

Comment: you need to iterate through `recipe.Ingredients` in the view via a for or foreach loop and display whatever data from each ingredient that you want

Comment: I can't do that. It gives me this error: "foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type Recipe because Recipe does not contain a public instance definition for GetEnumerator"

Comment: Nevermind, I managed to solve it. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to include the recipe's ingredients when querying them out of the db.

i.e: replace

`db.Recipes.Find(id);`

with

`db.Recipes.Include(x => x.Ingredients).Single(y => y.Id == id);`

To display ingredient details, you need to loop through the ingredients and show whatever data from each ingredient you want.

i.e: replace

```
 <dd>
     @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Ingredients)
 </dd>
```

with

```
@foreach(var ingredient in Model.Ingredients)
{
     /*feel free to format/display this however you want.
       this is only intended to show you how to accomplish
       what you're asking*/

     Nume: @ingredient.Nume
     Carbo: @ingredient.Carbo
     Pro: @ingredient.Pro
}
```

You could also create a display template that takes an `IList<Ingredient>` as a model. If you did that, you would not need to change your current model at all as `DisplayFor` will automatically look for a display template to use.